# User browser, os, flash etc. info

Tags: browser, operating-system, analytics

I need a way to get user information for individual users on my website.

I can use Google Analytics but I don't know how to extract and send it to a php script when a user submits a form.

I prefer to use Google Analytics since it would save me a lot of work, but I would use another script or put in original code to get the following:

browsers,
operating systems,
screen colors,
screen resolutions,
java support,
Flash

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect an overall view rather than tying the information to each user you could put Google Analytics on the page your form submits to. Otherwise you're going to have to roll your own or use a solution from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of doing some programming yourself, have a look at [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). It is an open source analytics application much like Google Analytics.
You can extend it via plugins and define your own data you want to collect.

(Of course if you don't create a custom plugin, you do not need to program something to use Piwik)